# Does MS Project 2007 require SharePoint & How useful is MS Project to your development team?

Tags: ms-project

Lets try this one more time.  I'm posting this to get 2 questions answered

1. Does MS Project 2007 require
   SharePoint (I am hoping no)?
2. Do
   you like MS Project for your
   development team - is it useful or a
   pain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't require sharepoint, but there are a whole host of features that can only be exposed via sharepoint.

The biggest problem IMO with MS project is that it relies on there being a single point of management (the project manager) where all information gets submitted then the project plan etc is updated from there. The project manager then has to redistribute the information. Other project management software like fogbugz allows all users to submit information and has a highly visible view of the project. I've found this to be a far more useful way for managing projects and makes it much easier to evaluate what the status of the project really is.